# Which attributes from a fitted regression are diagnostics for collinearity?

Tags: multiple-regression, multicollinearity

Here's my list of what I think the relevant attributes are:

1. Autocorrelation in the residuals.
2. A comparison between the significance of the overall-F statistic and the t-statistics for the individual coefficients.
3. The VIF for the coefficients.
4. The leverage plots.
5. Large standard errors on the regression coefficients.

But I'm thinking that it's not possible for all of these attributes to indicate collinearity, especially the comparison between the significance of the overall-F statistic and the t-statistics for the individual coefficients. I'd appreciate any further insight or ways to think about it!